# Word for "credit stealer"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, synonyms

While reading the novel "One night at call center", I came across this:

> He's such a loser who steals credit of others. 
>   Viroom, we must teach a lesson to this *credit stealer*.

Now, I just want to know the synonym or a word to call people who steal credit of others, as in if a person A has done a task, but person B poses to the world that it was done by him and takes the credit instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a child, we called such people "glory hogs". That I haven't heard the term since suggests that it was regional slang, but the sense would be clear to people unfamiliar with the term, so it may still serve informally.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is an exact match, but I would suggest **hog**.

- He hogged the limelight by pretending the work was his.

The word *hog* has, among others, the following meanings:

- A greedy person
- An inconsiderate boor

As a verb, it could mean

- To take or use selfishly

However, without the object *limelight*, the meaning may not necessarily be conveyed.